# Unicode font Posts, messages not saving on facebook

Tags: facebook, unicode, fonts, typography

I have a font based on the UNICODE Private Use Area (PUA). It makes use of the range U+E001 to U+E114. After installing the font on my Windows 7 laptop, I was able to type, save and retrieve text on Wordpad. I then set the font in Chrome and was able to send and receive emails using the font. Great!

I want to be able to send messages and posts to my timeline on facebook, so a group of us could study the script further. I could type and send text normally but only a blank message or post is received. Moreover, if I exit and relaunch facebook, the previous message disappears.  In its place I see the message :**Attachment Unavailable. This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared**

Am I breaching any security protocol? Doesn't facebook recognise PUA fonts?

Can anyone help please?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question, and should rather be directed at Facebook end user support.

Comment: Sure it's not a purely programming issue although some might suggest a programming solution for it.  I get problems beyond facebook as with Skype chat for example.  This is a question about the feasibility of PUA based fonts across the web.